# scp a file in parallel FROM multiple servers

Tags: ssh, scp, parallel-processing

Is there a script or something that can use **scp** to copy a single file from multiple servers/sources, each connection with its own chunk/chunks? I want something like how a torrent acts. I do not have an option to actually run a torrent server. I am sure the files is in the same path over all those servers, and contains that exact same file.

Answer (score -1):

This May work for you if you keep your files in 1 location(/tmp) of Multiple servers else if you want to keep in 2-3 location then need if-else loop

```
for i in Node1 Node2 Node3 .....;
do;
  scp root@$i:/tmp/ /tmp;
done
```

Comment: Can you please detail your solution, please? What it does? Why it works?

Comment: Ok you want single file to be copied from Multiple servers...I given you solution to copy multiple files from Multiple servers to your local server.

Comment: May be we can append ...

Comment: This code loops in sequence, it is not parallel. For this reason alone it is not what the OP wants. You have noticed in your comment the OP wants a single file. Even if you put `scp`s in background and they download the same file, each process will try to get the whole file. Am I wrong? Probably they will disturb one another by writing to the same destination. In the best case you will have the file as soon as the fastest server delivers it, with multiple `scp`s still overwriting it with the same content in background.